# Remove quantity field from WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I implemented on my e-commerce the variations choose in shop page in the `content-product.php`:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_quantity_input', 30 );
/*remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart_quantity', 30 );*/
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );              
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' ); 
?>
```

I want to remove the quantity selector from home page. How can I remove it using `remove_action`?

Comment: Can't you just set the item to be sold individually? That will remove all the quantity selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this hook in functions.php file

```
/**
 * @desc Remove in all product type
 */
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any scripts or coding.

WP-Admin -> Products -> Open your product -> Select Inventory -> Select "Sold Individually".